# removing custom stop words form a phrase in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, stop-words

I am trying to remove certain phrases and words form a user input before I further process the input and while trying to do that I'm running into a problem of getting an "index out of range" error and am completely stuck. How do I solve this? 
I get my input phrase as a string which I convert to a list to compare every word and I have my stop words as a predefined list.
Example inputs:
["well","you","know","the","weather","is","awful"]
["you", "know", "what", "i", "mean", "so", "just", "turn", "the", "lights", "on"]

```
#Gets user input and removes the selected stop words from it and returns a filtered phrase back.    
def stop_word_remover(phrase_list):

    stop_words_lst = ["yo", "so", "well", "um", "a", "the","you know", "i mean"]

    #initalize clean phrase string
    clean_input_phrase= ""

    #copying phrase_list into a new variable for stopword removal.
    Copy_phrase_list = list(phrase_list)

    #Cleanup loop

    for i in range(1,len(phrase_list)):
        has_stop_words = False

        for x in range(len(stop_words_lst)):
            has_stop_words = False

            #if one of the stop words matches the word passed by the first main loop      the  flag is raised.
            if (phrase_list[i-1]+" "+phrase_list[i]) == stop_words_lst[x].strip():
                has_stop_words = True    

            # this if statement adds the word of the phrase only if the flag is not raised thus making sure all the stop words are filtered out         
            if has_stop_words == True:
                Copy_phrase_list.remove(Copy_phrase_list[i-1])
                Copy_phrase_list.remove(Copy_phrase_list[i-1])

    #first for loop takes a individual words of the phrase given and makes a loop until the whole phrase goes through one word at a time
    for i in range(len(Copy_phrase_list)):
        #flag initialized for marking stop words
        has_stop_words = False

        #second loop takes all the stop words and compares them to the first word passed on by the first loop to sheck for a stop word
        for x in range(len(stop_words_lst)):
            #if one of the stop words matches the word passed by the first main loop the  flag is raised.
            if Copy_phrase_list[i] == stop_words_lst[x].strip():
            has_stop_words = True    

        # this if statement adds the word of the phrase only if the flag is not raised thus making sure all the stop words are filtered out        
        if has_stop_words == False:
            clean_input_phrase += str(Copy_phrase_list[i]) +" "


return clean_input_phrase
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Can you correct it and also provide example of input to the function and expected output.

Comment: @Marcin the input function could be any kind of phrase / command. It is just meant to remove these from a input before being analyzed further. But I did fix the indentation and added some example phrases.

Comment: I tried your [code](http://pastebin.com/VbZ2pBsR), and I dont get any errors. It seems to work for me.

Comment: It runs but returns the wrong output. Instead of taking "you know what i mean so just turn the lights on", removing the "you know", "i mean", "so" and "the" and returning "what just turn lights on". It returns "what i mean turn lights on " @Marcin Also it seems to work for some and not for others. like ["you","know","lock","my","computer","yo","man","you","know"] doest seem to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the regular expression substitute function.
Replace each match with an empty string.

```
stop_words_lst = ['yo', 'so', 'well', 'um', 'a', 'the', 'you know', 'i mean']
s = "you know what i mean so just turn the lights on"

import re
for w in stop_words_lst:
    pattern = r'\b'+w+r'\b'
    s = re.sub(pattern, '', s)
    print (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your word lists. One should be for single words and another should be for phrases.

```
single_word_list = ["yo", "so", "well", "um", "a", "the"]
phrase_list = ["you know", "i mean"]
for index, word in enumerate(Copy_phrase_list) :
    if word in single_word_lst:
        del Copy_phrase_list[index] 
    if word + " " + Copy_phrase_list[index+1] in phrase_list:
        del Copy_phrase_list[index] 
        del Copy_phrase_list[index+1] 
return " ".join(Copy_phrase_list)
```

And then you need to convert copy_phrase_list to a string and return it.

Comment: Remove all your for loops and add the following for loop. You'll be done.

Comment: it doesnt seem to remove the two word phrases such as "you know" and "i mean" @geekpradd

Comment: All right, I did not see that.. Let me hack something up. Wait some time.

Comment: that would be awesome if you could come up with something or improve upon mine. The purpose is for me to be able to add more multi word phrases or single words to the stop word list as I go revising this project and the code to still work on removing them form a user given input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73823/discussion-between-valus-sulav-and-geekpradd).